# Create and download text files- Node.js & React.Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

As part of my project, I have to create text files which have to be downloaded as a ".txt".
I am using Node.js and React JavaScript, and I have already tried using the Node.js "fs.writeFile", but the browser doesn't recognize the download, the file name is always being called as the folder name and the file is always empty although the variable is a string and not empty.
I'm calling from the client to this function:

```
app.post("/downloadnetworks", async (req, res) => {
  let selectedApps=req.body.selectedApps;
  let arr=await sqlFunctions.createByIds(selectedApps);
  res.send();
```

```js
module.exports.createByIds = (productsArray) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          var bulkedString = '';
          var product;
          for (let obj of productsArray) {
            let query = "select * from...........";
            con.query(query, function(err, result, fields) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  let stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify(result)
                  let parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson)
```

The DB data is being added into the variable 'stringifiedJson', and it continues from here:

```js
let parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson) //has all the data from the DB
for (let network of parsedJson) {
  if (network.certification_Id) {
    bulkedString += network.domain_Name + ", " + network.publisher_Id + ", " + network.relationship + ", " + network.certification_Id;
  } else {
    bulkedString += network.domain_Name + ", " + network.publisher_Id + ", " +
      network.relationship;
  }
  bulkedString += "\n";
  product = network.product;
}
})

fs.writeFile('C:\Work\App ads.txt\App-Ads Files\'' + product + '.txt', bulkedString, 'utf8', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
}
resolve(bulkedString)
})
}
```

Comment: is bulkedString defined before? can you try console.log it before you call fs?

Comment: @Elad Hi Elad,
Yes, I have defined it before, and the console log is displaying the string as needed.
תודה על העזרה!

Comment: Are you waiting for the file to be completely written? maybe try use writeFileSync

Comment: @Elad
Hi Elad, I just checked again and it seems that the 'bulkedString' is becoming undefined when it gets into the fs.writeFile.
It's weird because I defined it as "Var", at the function beginning, and it appearing as expected on the "console log" before closing the for loop brackets.

Comment: @Elad
I edited the code at the above.

Comment: maybe the fs is starting before the query ends? it's hard to tell, can you post the whole function till the resolve

Comment: @Elad I edited the post and added all the functions.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206771/discussion-between-elad-and-elick-chitrit).